# implement MapView event listeners on Android

Tags: java, android, events, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Android's MapView. I am trying to implement event listeners that can correspond to the following actions:

- newLocation
- LocationError
- regionWillChange
- regionDidChange
- WillStartLoadingMap
- DidFinishLoadingMap
- DidFailLoadingMap
- didAddAnnotation
- clickAnnotation
- leftClicked
- rightClicked

Any ideas anyone? Would really appreciate a helping hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those exist in the Google APIs Add-On for Android, sorry.